# How do I get a for loop working within a functional component reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, syntax-error, react-functional-component

I was wondering if I could get some help please, I'm currently trying to relearn ReactJS and I am working on this task that is a little app that would help kids to learn their times tables. **When the user clicks on a number from the grid then all the multiples of that number would change colour / do something.** I currently have the following but I would really appreciate some help with the last bit please if possible:
I have the numbers mapping to the grid, 
I have a function that finds the multiples of whatever number you pass through from the array of numbers I have passed through, 
 
But I am struggling to get the two working with each other, at the moment I have the value of the number that the user selects on when they click on a number on the grid, but I can't seem to use that value in the `multipleFinder` function as a parameter, it just doesn't even recognise it as a second parameter. I tried moving that whole function into the functional component `MapThis` but I kept getting the error 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` 
or 
`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` 
I have tried moving it around and changing the code but I just seem to keep getting the same errors or not much of a response, I've been trying to get this to work for quite a few days now, I'm thinking it could be an error with the loop maybe? / trying to use it within a functional component. I'm not sure if I'm just on the wrong path for what I'm trying to achieve but any help would be much appreciated! Thank you! :)

Everything in my component file currently:

```
import './NumberGridStyles.css';

// Get all the numbers from 1 - 144
let numbersStart = 1;
let numbersEnd = 144;
let allNumbers = Array(numbersEnd - numbersStart + 1)
    .fill()
    .map(() => numbersStart++);

function MultipleFinder(allthenumbers, multipleno) {
    var multiples = [allNumbers];
    for (var i = 0; i < allthenumbers.length; i++) {
        if (allthenumbers[i] % multipleno === 0) {
            multiples.push(allthenumbers[i]);
        }
    }
    return multiples;
}
// return MultipleFinder();
console.log(MultipleFinder(allNumbers, 20));


// Map all 1 - 144 numbers to the grid
export const MapThis = () => {

    function showTheMultiples(allNumbers) {
        console.log(allNumbers);
        MultipleFinder(allNumbers, 6);
        console.log(MultipleFinder(allNumbers, 10))
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="wrapper">
                {allNumbers.map(allNumbers => (
                    <div className="box" key={allNumbers.toString()} onClick={() => showTheMultiples(allNumbers)}>
                        {allNumbers}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The CSS file:

```
body {
    margin: 40px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
  }

  .box {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
  }
```

[Screenshot of the grid and the array of numbers based on the second parameter you pass through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh6mo.png)

Comment: Where you are doing  `{allNumbers.map(allNumbers => (....)}` change the name inside allNumbers to other name, but im not sure if thats the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the name the var inside `allnumbers.map` to `number` and changed all ocurrences inside map to it; and, changed the function `showTheMultiples` to actually show all numbers list and multiple numbers list, and it works.

```js
export const MapThis = () => {

    function showTheMultiples(number) {
        console.log(allNumbers);
        MultipleFinder(allNumbers, number);
        console.log(MultipleFinder(allNumbers, number))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="wrapper">
                {allNumbers.map(number => (
                    <div className="box" key={number.toString()} onClick={() => showTheMultiples(number)}>
                        {number}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If you want change the style of the multiple itens you can add a state to save the list of multiples and a renderList function that gets allNumbers var and multipleNumbers (state var). So, for each item on allNumers list, you can verify it it's within multipleNumbers, if it's true, change the style to 'multiple' or something like that, if not change style to 'box'.

If you want an example of a code that

> When the user clicks on a number from the grid then all the multiples of that number would change colour / do something

...[try this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-glade-zcro2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). That's a sandbox with your issue solved.

Comment: Thank you so much, @RafaelBarbosa and Josep for all your help I gave both a try I really appreciate the help and all the effort you've gone to, to help me solve this problem. I gave both ways a try and both work perfectly! You've saved me from pulling my hair out, I'd been going round in circles for days, the working solution looks great, thank you so much or explaining what changes you made to make it work too and what I would need to do to get the multiples to change colour onclick, this was a big learning curve for me, thank you so much again guys! :) 